# Jquery - Get all visible children from a div Get

Tags: jquery

I can get all the children of an element with this code

```
$('#all').children().each(function() { .... });
```

But how can i get all visible children with class "one" from `id="all"` ?

```
<div id="all">

    <div>asdd</div>
    <div class="one">content</div>
    <div class="one">bla</div>

    <div>
        ssss
        <div class="one" style="display:none">text</div>
    </div>

    <div class="one" style="display:none">blub</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 20):

You can use the [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) filter selector like this:

```
$('#all').find('.one:visible').each(function(){
  // your code....
});
```

Answer (score 5):

**You can use the following simple jQuery function**

```
$('#all .one:visible');
```

This will get you all the visible elements with class one. (enclosed within the #all)

Answer (score 3):

Would this work?

```
$('.one:visible', '#all')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this example

```js
            $(document).ready(function(){
            
                $('#all').children().each(function() { 
                    if($(this).hasClass('one') && $(this).css('display') != 'none')
                    {
                        alert($(this).html());
                    }
                });
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="all">
    
            <div>asdd</div>
            <div class="one">content</div>
            <div class="one">bla</div>
    
            <div>
                ssss
                <div class="one" style="display:none">text</div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="one" style="display:none">blub</div>
    
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```